# cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll is missing to run software SPEED in Cygwin

Tags: performance, cygwin

I am unable to run my software "SPEED" in CYGWIN, because of the error - "cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll is missing". Can someone suggest which package should I download in Cygwin to fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

To find the package containing a file use `cygcheck`

```
 $ cygcheck -p cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
Found 6 matches for cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
gcc-debuginfo-5.3.0-5 - gcc-debuginfo: Debug info for gcc (installed binaries and support files)
gcc-debuginfo-5.4.0-1 - gcc-debuginfo: Debug info for gcc (installed binaries and support files)
gcc-debuginfo-6.3.0-1 - gcc-debuginfo: Debug info for gcc
libgcc1-5.3.0-5 - libgcc1: GCC C runtime library (installed binaries and support files)
libgcc1-5.4.0-1 - libgcc1: GCC C runtime library (installed binaries and support files)
libgcc1-6.3.0-1 - libgcc1: GCC C runtime library
```

It is unlikely that you have `libgcc1-5.4.0-1` not installed. (version 6.3.0 is test, so you don't need it)